# C++ Builder 10.3 can not assign to const wchar_t* from const char[18]

Tags: c++, builder

I have a simple code for directories handling, and here is a part of it. The problem is, that in older version of builder(I guess it is 6) it was working perfectly, now it throws
`[bcc32c Error] Unit1.cpp(32): assigning to 'PCZZWSTR' (aka 'const wchar_t *') from incompatible type 'const char [18]'`.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fos;
String dirDest;
fos.hwnd = Handle;
//operacja kopiowania
fos.wFunc = FO_COPY;
//plik źródłowy
fos.pFrom = "C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy";
}
```

The problem is with line `fos.pFrom = "C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy";`. I tried assigning `"C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy"` to `const wchar_t*` using linkig, but it thrown me that it can not be linked. Does somebody have a clue how to fix it?

Comment: The member `pFrom` of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` is a `PCZZTSTR`, aka an array of `TCHAR` (that in your case is `WCHAR`) terminated by two null characters. So I think you should use a wide string literal like this: `fos.pFrom = L"C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy\0";` or `w_str()` on a VCL `UnicodeString`

Comment: @MatG it gives me `[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Vcl::Filectrl::SelectDirectory(System::UnicodeString&, System::Set<Vcl::Filectrl::TSelectDirOpt, 0, 2>, int)' referenced from C:\USERS\LEONM\DESKTOP\ARC\WIN32\DEBUG\UNIT1.OBJ`

Comment: @miś-kolorowy Lot of things are changed from BCB6, for example `AnsiString` was replaced by `UnicodeString`; you should google about porting old BCB projects. If you want help here, you should try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MatG `UnicodeString::w_str()` is long deprecated, use `UnicodeString::c_str()` instead.

Comment: @miś_kolorowy don't migrate an old project to a new IDE version. Create a new project and add your existing source files to it as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, `UnicodeString::c_str()` points to `WideChar`. You know, the 16 bit unicode embraced by Windows, VCL, Java, Qt, ... makes me so sad, what a poor choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `TCHAR`-based version of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT`, so its string fields will be based on either `wchar_t` or `char` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

In C++Builder 6 (where `String` was an alias for `AnsiString`), `UNICODE` was not defined by default. In C++Builder 2009 onward (where `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString`), `UNICODE` is defined by default, but [can be turned off](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TCHAR_Mapping) if needed for legacy projects.

Since you are using a `TCHAR`-based struct, you should use the `TCHAR`-based [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro when defining *string literals* for it, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fos;
    fos.hwnd = Handle;
    //operacja kopiowania
    fos.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    //plik źródłowy
    fos.pFrom = TEXT("C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy\0"); // don't forget the extra null terminator!
    fos.pTo = TEXT("...\0");
    ...
    SHFileOperation(&fos);
}
```

That will work in all C++Builder versions.

On the other hand, if you are trying to use a `String` variable to define strings for the struct, that will work only if `UNICODE` is *undefined* in pre-2009 versions, and *defined* in post-2009 versions, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    String dirSrc("C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy\0", 18); // don't forget the extra null terminator!
    String disDest(...);
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fos;
    fos.hwnd = Handle;
    //operacja kopiowania
    fos.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    //plik źródłowy
    fos.pFrom = dirSrc.c_str();
    fos.pTo = dirDest.c_str();
    ...
    SHFileOperation(&fos);
}
```

If you don't want to rely on the `UNICODE` define, then you should use the ANSI or Unicode version of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` explicitly, depending on whether you are working with ANSI (`char`) or Unicode (`wchar_t`) strings, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    SHFILEOPSTRUCTA fos;
    fos.hwnd = Handle;
    //operacja kopiowania
    fos.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    //plik źródłowy
    fos.pFrom = "C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy\0"; // don't forget the extra null terminator!
    fos.pTo = "...\0";
    ...
    SHFileOperationA(&fos);
}
```

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fos;
    fos.hwnd = Handle;
    //operacja kopiowania
    fos.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    //plik źródłowy
    fos.pFrom = L"C:\\Melon\\AGA\\Bazy\0"; // don't forget the extra null terminator!
    fos.pTo = L"...\0";
    ...
    SHFileOperationW(&fos);
}
```